# How can I specify at which level the toc will be expanded in an Rmd report?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, tableofcontents

When generating an Rmarkdown `.html` document, is it possible to selectivey choose the default section of the table of contents at which it will be displayed? I have an ongoing Rmd report which is updated regularly, and I would like the previous toc sections to be available but collapsed and only the latest (or explicitly indicated section) expanded.

````
---
title: "Main document"
date: "16 March 2018"
output: 
  html_document:
    mode: selfcontained
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_depth: 2
---

```{r child = 'document1.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'document2.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'document3.Rmd'}
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a tiny `JavaScript` program that uses the [`window.location` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

Here's a reproducible `Rmd` opening the subsection 2.1:

````
---
title: "Document"
date: "16 March 2018"
output: 
  html_document:
    mode: selfcontained
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_depth: 2
---
# Section 1
## Subsection 1.1

## Subsection 1.2

# Section 2
## Subsection 2.1

## Subsection 2.2

```{js echo=FALSE}
window.location.href='#subsection_21';
```
````

In order to adapt this example to your document:

1. Open the `HTML` document in a browser, select the targeted section and read the browser address bar. The address ends with `#section_title_or_something_like_that`. Note this `id`.
2. Copy the `js` chunk of the example at the very end of your main `Rmd` file. Replace
   `#subsection_21` with the previous `id` (`#section_title_or_something_like_that`).
3. `Knit` your main document! That's done.

---

If you want to avoid raw JavaScript in your main `Rmd` file, you also can include theses lines in a `script.html` file (do not forget to adapt the `id`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href='#subsection_21';
</script>
```

Then, includes this `script.html` file in your document using:

```
---
title: "Document"
date: "16 March 2018"
output: 
  html_document:
    mode: selfcontained
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_depth: 2
    includes:
      after_body: "script.html"
---
# Section 1
## Subsection 1.1

## Subsection 1.2

# Section 2
## Subsection 2.1

## Subsection 2.2
```

Comment: I tested this and it worked. However, in an updated version of my .Rmd document it doesn't work anymore. I am following exaclty the same steps you mention. Do you think there's anything else that could stop this working? thank you.

Comment: Maybe the browser: try with different browsers and tell me

Comment: Tested on updated versions of chrome, firefox and edge... it does not work in any of them (html document starts at the first toc title)

Comment: It's weird. Could you try to externalize the `js` script? I updated the answer: see the second part.